# Proper way to add this library in my project

Tags: android, github, custom-controls

I just downloaded this -> https://github.com/borax12/MaterialDateRangePicker/releases

Inside the downloaded folder is this [image]

I'm a newbie in android, what should i do to use this in project without messing around with the packages. Create a project and copy-paste it in praying to the bug gods?

Comment: why don't you use gradle ?

Comment: Try reading the `README`, which will lead you to the [parent `README`](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker).

Answer (score 2):

You need to add it to your gradle.
To do this go to the left hand menu of Android Studio.

1) Click on app

2) Gradle Scripts

3) build.gradle(the second one, should say Module.app)

4) Scroll all the way to the bottom where it says dependencies then add this line

```
repositories {
  jcenter()
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.borax12.materialdaterangepicker:library:1.9'
}
```

5) Then build your project and you should be good to go!